# Mongo. Return related collections on parent

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Assuming such a mongoose database schema,

```js
const teacherSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
name: {type: String, required: true, trim: true},
})


const courseSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
name: {type: String, required: true, trim: true},
teacher: { type: 'ObjectId', ref: 'Teacher', required: true },
})


const studentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
name: {type: String, required: true, trim: true},
course: { type: 'ObjectId', ref: 'Course', required: true },
})


const hobbySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
name: {type: String, required: true, trim: true},
student: { type: 'ObjectId', ref: 'Student', required: true },
})
```

How can I query and return data from a specific teacher, while nesting courses they teach, students taking the course and their hobbies?
***NOTE:** I find teacher using url params (id)*

```js
{
_id: "61040a6dec6d054128fa8eae",
name: "John Doe",
others: ...,
courses: [
 {
   content: ...,
   students: [
    {
     content: ....,
     hobbies: [{
      content:...
     }
     ]
    },
    {...other students taking the course}
   ]
 },
 {...other subjects by John Doe}
]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need is [mongo aggregate](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) to link and obtain data from different schemas.

First, introduce a relationship linking all schemas, just like how you doing with the ref, I suggest have a
`usersSchema` and introduce a `userType` field that identifies the type of user either student or teacher, so you can do away with teacherSchema and studentSchema

```
UserSchema.aggregate([
        {
            $match: { id: teacherId }
        },
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: "users",
            localField: "students",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "students",
          },
        },
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: "hobbies",
            localField: "hobbyId",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "hobbies",
          },
        },
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: "course",
            localField: "courseId",
            foreignField: "_id",
            as: "courses",
          },
        },
        {
          $sort: {
            createdAt: -1,
          },
        },
        {
          $unwind: "$users",
        },
      ])
        .then((data) => {
          return data
        })
```